# Alternative for running a function in background mode

Tags: swift, push-notification, nstimer

I am creating an app where it will send you a local notification every 20 minutes. The problem I am having is once the app goes into background mode, the timer which triggers the function to run which executes some code then sends the user a notification won't run. Is there any alternative way of doing this? This timer runs on a loop, reseting its self every 20 minutes and running a function.

Thanks

Comment: What are you doing in this function that you want to periodically run in the background? There are a few, specialized cases were background operation is permitted. But, in general, you cannot do what you're asking (because tons of apps would start doing that, and it would kill our batteries). But if we know what you're trying to do, we might be able to offer counsel.

Comment: By the way, the [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1) chapter of the _App Programming Guide for iOS_ clearly outlines all of these different scenarios.

Comment: Thanks rob. I am trying to fire local notifications every 20 minutes, although inbetween these notifications I must run a function to still check if they are needed. If that helps?

Comment: Sadly, no, that's still too ambiguous. The background execution criteria are quite specific and narrow (e.g. VOIP, navigation, music, etc.). And other types of background operation (e.g. fetching data from network periodically) are further constrained (e.g. you can't decide with what frequency it will be called; the OS decides that for you). Again, without more specifics of what precisely this function is trying to do, we cannot help.

Comment: The function is checking the current time against a time window set by the user and if the current time is inside that window I want it to continue to sending notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Check out the documentation for `UILocalNotification`. You can set a `fireDate` to the exact second when you want the notification to go off. It also has parameters you can use to specify a repeat interval.

You cannot force the user to activate the app to run your function. Once the user taps the notification and your app becomes active, you can then perform all the logic you require (perhaps also including dealing with past "missed" notifications) .

Comment: Thanks but I have already done this, this isn't the problem. The problem is I need to run the function as it executes some code to check something then if that something is correct to be able to send another push notification. The problem is I can;t run the function in background mode...

Comment: You cannot force the user to activate the app to run your function. Once the user taps the notification and your app becomes active, you can then perform all the logic you require (perhaps also including dealing with past "missed" notifications) .

Comment: Again this isn't the solution as I need this function to be ran in background mode. Not for the user to open the app and then function be ran, as this is not the answer. The notifications being sent out are reminders for something, and they are sent out every 20 minutes unless some code inside the function is negative. So I am looking for an alternative for how I can run this function in the background, or something which will achieve the same end result.

Comment: As stated, this is impossible. The only background activity you can run is downloads. You need to revise your architecture and find a way to determine the correct behavior **without** running your function.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. As stated I have asked for an alternative thou, I was already aware this is impossible.